# Which design pattern shall I choose? Decorate or Chain of responsibility or something else

Tags: design-patterns

I need to add various attributes to various elements in a XML document, the logics for adding new attributes are very independent. I will create a bunch of classes to adding those attributes, I am wondering which design pattern I should use, I thought of the following options:

1. Decorator
   Too many subclasses. I may have 10 to 20 modules to decorate the XML, but I don't like 20 subclasses.
2. Chain of Responsibility:
   I don't want individual module to finish the whole process, because they are independent.

Any suggestion is highly welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually given that much context to go on.  Programming language, which XML parsing model you're using, and how much context is needed to determine whether a given element needs attributes.

So here's one approach that:

- assumes Java
- uses an abstract notional set of objects (Element and XMLDocument) that's a bit similar to the DOM approach - replace with whatever your real interface is to the nodes in the XML tree
- assumes that the element matching logic is self-contained, meaning your logic can tell whether a specific attribute should be applied based on the name or other attributes in the Element itself, and don't need to know about parents, children, or ancestors

By the way - this code hasn't been compiled and tested.  It's just an illustration of the approach.

```
public interface ElementManipulator {
    public void manipulateElement(Element elem);
}

public class AManipulator implements ElementManipulator {
    public void manipulateElement(Element elem) {
        if (elem.name == "something-A-cares-about") {
            //add A's attribute(s) to elem
        }
    }
}

public class BManipulator implements ElementManipulator {
    public void manipulateElement(Element elem) {
        if (elem.name == "something-B-cares-about") {
            //add B's attribute(s) to elem
        }
    }
}

public class XMLManipulator {
    ArrayList<? extends ElementManipulator> manipulators;

    public XMLManipulator () {
        this.manipulators = new ArrayList<? extends ElementManipulator>();
        this.manipulators.add(new AManipulator());
        this.manipulators.add(new BManipulator());
    }

    public void manipulateXMLDocument(XMLDocument doc) {
        Element rootElement = doc.getRootElement();
        this.manipulateXMLElement(rootElement);
    }        

    /**
     * Give the provided element, and all of it's children, recursively, 
     * to all of the manipulators on the list.
     */
    public void manipulateXMLElement(Element elem) {
        foreach (ElementManipulator manipulator : manipulators) {
            manipulator.manipulateElement(elem);
        }            
        ArrayList<Element> children = elem.getChildren();
        foreach(Element child: children) {
            this.manipulateXMLElement(child);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your assumption are all correct, I am using java XML Dom. I have one context object which contains all the info for manipulate XML.